# Asp.Net: Gridview OnPageIndexChanging not firing server method

Tags: asp.net, gridview, aspxgridview

I am not able to change the page index of the gridview. The server method for **OnPageIndexChanging** is not at all getting fired. I do not know what am I doing wrong here.

Here's my gridview

```
<asp:GridView ID="VideoCommentsGrid" runat="server" 
                        OnRowDataBound="VideoCommentsGrid_RowDataBound" 
                        OnPageIndexChanging="VideoCommentsGrid_PageIndexChanging" allowpaging="true" 
                        CssClass="tables" 
                        EmptyDataText="<div class='notice show bottom'>No Comments found.</div>" 
                        AutoGenerateColumns="False" >
                <Columns>
                    <asp:TemplateField HeaderStyle-HorizontalAlign="center" HeaderStyle-Width="70" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="center">
                        <HeaderTemplate>
                            Approve
                            <br />
                            <input id="ChkAllApprovedItems"  type="checkbox" />
                        </HeaderTemplate>
                        <ItemTemplate>
                            <asp:CheckBox ID="chkApproval" Checked='<%#Eval("IsApproved").ToString()=="1"?true:false %>'  runat="server"  />
                            <asp:Label ID="lblCommentID" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("CommentId") %>' CssClass="hide"/>
                         </ItemTemplate>
                        <HeaderStyle HorizontalAlign="Center" />
                        <ItemStyle HorizontalAlign="Center" />
                    </asp:TemplateField>

                     <asp:TemplateField HeaderStyle-HorizontalAlign="center" HeaderStyle-Width="70" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="center">
                        <HeaderTemplate>
                            Reject
                            <br />
                            <input id="ChkAllRejectedItems"  type="checkbox" />
                        </HeaderTemplate>
                        <ItemTemplate>
                            <asp:CheckBox ID="chkReject" Checked='<%#Eval("IsRejected").ToString()=="1"?true:false %>'  runat="server"  />
                         </ItemTemplate>
                        <HeaderStyle HorizontalAlign="Center" />
                        <ItemStyle HorizontalAlign="Center" />
                    </asp:TemplateField>

                    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="User Name" HeaderStyle-Width="70" >
                        <ItemTemplate>
                            <asp:Label ID="lblUserName" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("FirstName")%>'>  </asp:Label>
                        </ItemTemplate>
                        <HeaderStyle HorizontalAlign="Center" Width="150" />
                        <ItemStyle HorizontalAlign="Left" CssClass="wordWrap" Width="150" />
                    </asp:TemplateField>
                    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Comments" HeaderStyle-Width="70" >
                        <ItemTemplate>
                            <asp:Label ID="lblComment" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("VideoComment") %>' />
                        </ItemTemplate>
                        <HeaderStyle HorizontalAlign="Center" Width="150" />
                        <ItemStyle HorizontalAlign="Left" CssClass="wordWrap" Width="150" />
                    </asp:TemplateField>
                    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Comment Time* ">
                        <ItemTemplate>
                            <asp:Label ID="lblCommentDate" runat="server" Text='<%#(Eval("CommentCreatedDate"))%>'> </asp:Label>
                        </ItemTemplate>
                        <HeaderStyle HorizontalAlign="Center" Width="80" />
                        <ItemStyle HorizontalAlign="Center" Width="80" />
                    </asp:TemplateField>

                </Columns>
                <HeaderStyle Height="30" />
                <PagerStyle HorizontalAlign="Center" CssClass="footer" />
                <AlternatingRowStyle CssClass="odd" />

            </asp:GridView>
```

My server side code is as follows,

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
        LoadCommentsGridView(VideoCommentsGrid.PageIndex);
}

protected void VideoCommentsGrid_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
    if (!e.Row.RowType.Equals(DataControlRowType.DataRow)) return;

}
protected void VideoCommentsGrid_PageIndexChanging(object sender, GridViewPageEventArgs e)
{
    VideoCommentsGrid.PageIndex = e.NewPageIndex;
    LoadCommentsGridView(VideoCommentsGrid.PageIndex);
    hidCheckedValue.Value = string.Empty;
}
protected void LoadCommentsGridView(int PageIndex)
{
    SetPageIndex(PageIndex);
    LoadDefaultGrid();
}
private void LoadDefaultGrid()
{
    VideoCommentsGrid.PageSize = CurrentSchoolDetails.PageViewCount;
    IList<Comment> allComments = CommentRepository.GetAllCommentsByVideoID(VideoID);
    BindDataControls.BindGridView(VideoCommentsGrid, allComments);
}
```

Please help me out,
Thanks.

Comment: what does your `SetPageIndex()` do?Sets the page index programmatically?

Comment: @Ates - Yes,I am setting page index programmatically

Comment: Well, I found this [GridView.PageIndexChanging Event](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridview.pageindexchanging.aspx), and it says `This event is not raised when you programmatically set the PageIndex property.`.And you actually do set the PageIndex property programmatically.

Comment: Thanks. Let me make the necessary changes and test it again.

Comment: Ok, if it works let me know.I think it could be good for others as a communnity wiki answer .

Comment: I tried it. But still I am not able to get the event raised.

Comment: Well, sorry about that, hope you solve it and let us know.

Comment: Thanks. I will definitely post the solution here

Answer (score 0):

on the `rowdatabound` method try to comment this piece of code and see what happen.

```
//if (!e.Row.RowType.Equals(DataControlRowType.DataRow)) return;
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this is occurring because you are binding the data to the GridView on every page load,  where as you only need to bind the data once initially and then again when the page index changes.

Try changing the code in the Page_Load method like so:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if(!IsPostBack)
    {
        LoadCommentsGridView(VideoCommentsGrid.PageIndex);
    }
}
```